# Is there a way to determine in which stage a keyword was executed(setup/step/teardown) inside the keyword?

Tags: robotframework

I want to run different steps in a keyword,according to the stage that the keyword was executed.

Comment: please improve your question/give more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. The list of [automatic variables available in Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) is available in the User Guide. There is no such thing as the source of the keyword call. There are many workarounds though. Either you use multiple keyword variations that call your "core" keyword, or you use an argument in your keyword (source) or a global variable. If you try and fail, share your attempt and people will try to help you.